# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un evento funcione en un elemento deshabilitado JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un `select` deshabilitado y quiero que sí se intenta de clickear o pasar por encima de él, muestre un mensaje para avisar la razón por la cual está deshabilitado, pero al parecer lo eventos no funcionan con elementos deshabilitados, entonces no sé sí haya una forma de hacer lo que digo, el método ya lo tengo, solo es hacerlo funcionar con un evento.
Dejo el `HTML` y el método en `JavaScript`

`HTML` del select

```
<div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="empleado" class="col-form-label">Empleado:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" onmouseover="empleadoIsEmpty()" id="empleado" name="empleado" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar empleado</option>
                    <?php 
                        for ($i=0; $i < count($empleados); $i++) { 
                            echo "<option value='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}'>{$empleados[$i]['nombres']} {$empleados[$i]['apellidos']}</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

`JS`

```
function empleadoIsEmpty(){
    empleado = document.forms["formRegistro"]["empleado"];

    if(empleado.disabled){
        msg = "<ul>";
        msg += "<li> Debes seleccionar fecha y sede para habilitar los empleados </li>" 
        msg += "</ul>";

        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML = msg;
    }else{
        console.log("no entré");
    }
}
```

Gracias por anticipado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que los elementos deshabilitados no activan los eventos del mouse.

Teniendo esto como base entonces se me ocurre crear una máscara dentro del padre contenedor del `select`. Dicha máscara tendrá una posición absoluta y será el elemento al cual se le asignará el evento y su propiedad `display` dependerá del estado en el que se encuentre el `select`:

```js
function empleadoIsEmpty(){
    empleado = document.forms["formRegistro"]["empleado"];

    if(empleado.disabled){
        msg = "<ul>";
        msg += "<li> Debes seleccionar fecha y sede para habilitar los empleados </li>" 
        msg += "</ul>";

        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML = msg;
    }else{
        console.log("no entré");
    }
}
```

```css
#contenedor{
  position: relative;
}

/* Aplicamos la instrucción de que si el elemento "empleado" es disabled entonces su elemento hermano "mascara" tendrá un display block */
#empleado:disabled + #mascara{
  display: block;
}

#mascara{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="formRegistro">
  <label for="empleado" class="col-form-label">Empleado:</label>
  <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3' id="contenedor">
    <select type="text" class="custom-select" id="empleado" name="empleado" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="0">Seleccionar empleado</option>
    </select>
    <div id="mascara" onmouseover="empleadoIsEmpty()"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="errores"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Eres el mejor, gracias, voy intentarlo a ver que me resulta

Comment: Tenía en mente meter el select en un div y ponerle el mouseover en ese div, al igual validar con js si tenía el atributo disabled activara la función, pero tu respuesta es mucho mejor.

Comment: @VickMuñoz yo también estaba pensandolo hacer así, pero ya Bender solucionó la vida

Comment: No se puede competir mucho con esos 10k de reputación :B

Comment: @VickMuñoz teníamos casi la misma solución jejejeje solo que con elementos diferentes a la hora de asignar el evento, saludos bro y gracias jejeje!

Comment: @DaxTter77 me alegra que te sirviera como solución, ahora no pude entender una de tus preguntas pero en esta si pude ayudarte jejejeje saludos!

Comment: De hecho ya lo estaba haciendo XD Pero me estaba haciendo un revolvedero y mejor lo dejé para los profesionales! hahahaha, saludos man! Nos estaremos leyendo :)

Comment: @BenderPaisa ésta es más importante, y aquí sí llegaste con tu capa de héroe, gracias, saludos men

Comment: @DaxTter77 @VickMuñoz cuando puedan pásense por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) allí podremos hablar y también resolver dudas :D un `@Bender` y me encuentran de una

Answer (score 3):

Como bien ha explicado @BenderPaisa en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/278141/16597) hay eventos que no se disparan sobre elementos `disabled`.

Mi solución en principio es similar, y se puede lograr el mismo comportamiento simplemente "*moviendo*" el `select` por "*debajo*" del contenedor.

#### Demo:

```js
function empleadoIsEmpty() {
  empleado = document.forms["formRegistro"]["empleado"];

  if (empleado.disabled) {
    msg = "<ul>";
    msg += "<li> Debes seleccionar fecha y sede para habilitar los empleados </li>"
    msg += "</ul>";

    document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML = msg;
  } else {
    console.log("no entré");
  }
}
```

```css
#empleado:disabled {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<form name="formRegistro">
  <label for="empleado" class="col-form-label">Empleado:</label>
  <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3' onmouseover="empleadoIsEmpty()">
    <select type="text" class="custom-select" id="empleado" name="empleado" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="0">Seleccionar empleado</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="errores"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias, un buen método también